# Can you check the licensing status of one application from a different application using the android lvl library?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-lvl

Suppose I have 2 applications published on Google Play, then can I check the licensing status of 2nd app from the 1st one using the android lvl (License Verification Library)?

Comment: Did you find out more on this? I tried substituting mPackageName and mVersionCode in LicenseChecker and everywhere else I could find a package name was used within LVL source code, but all I get is ERROR_INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME.

Comment: I was not able to find a solution for this hence I used a different approach for implementing the use case.

Comment: @gregko from what I was able to find, `ERROR_INVALID_PACKAGE_NAME` returns these details: `Local error — the application requested a license check for a package that is not installed on the device.` - [link here.](https://shorturl.at/svyE5) So I guess you can only check apps which are currently installed on the device :( Which kinda beats the purpose lol. I have a FREE app and a DONATION app and want to add paid features into my FREE app - but also grant access to all users who purchased DONATION app...This should be tied to google account, not to a local device, damn Googlers...

Comment: I did not find any solution, had to give up on this idea. It would be useful to do such check, at least among the apps of the same developer (singed with the same certificate), but the "Googlers" lack imagination, and as always, completely ignore requests from small developers.